# is there a way to truncate multiple functions into one?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my updated attempted based on help provided below. I wanted to make sure that this is going to properly calculate all 6 scenarios that are commented.

```
Sub recalc()
    Dim adjValue As String
    Dim runningTotal As Double
    
    runningTotal = 0
    
    'if user chooses 1 job to adjust or remove
    If opt1Req Then
        If optReduceReq Then
            'reduce $ from one job
            runningTotal = runningTotal + CDbl(txtAdjustmentAmt)
        ElseIf optRemoveReq Then
            'remove total $ from one job
            runningTotal = runningTotal + CDbl(txtBudgetImpact)
        End If
    'if user chooses 2 jobs to adjust or remove
    ElseIf opt2Reqs Then
        If optReduceReq_2 Then
            If optRemoveReq Then
                'remove total $ from 1st job // reduce $ from 2nd job
                runningTotal = runningTotal + CDbl(txtBudgetImpact) + CDbl(txtAdjustmentAmt_2)
            Else
                'reduce $ from 1st job // reduce $ from 2nd job
                runningTotal = runningTotal + CDbl(txtAdjustmentAmt) + CDbl(txtAdjustmentAmt_2)
            End If
        ElseIf optRemoveReq_2 Then
            If optRemoveReq Then
                'remove total $ from 1st and 2nd job
                runningTotal = runningTotal + CDbl(txtBudgetImpact) + CDbl(txtBudgetImpact_2)
            Else
                'reduce $ from 1st job // remove total $ from 2nd job
                runningTotal = runningTotal + CDbl(txtAdjustmentAmt) + CDbl(txtBudgetImpact_2)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    adjValue = CDbl(runningTotal)
    
    txtFunctionExcess.Value = FormattedRemainingBudget( _
        txtBudget.Value, adjValue)
    
    End If
End Sub
Function FormattedRemainingBudget(budget As String, adjustment As String) As String
    Dim dblBudget As Double: dblAdjust = CDbl(budget)
    Dim dblAdjust As Double: dblAdjust = CDbl(adjust)
    FormattedRemainingBudget = Format(dblBudget - dblAdjust, "$#,##.00")
End Function
```

This is my first time with attempting to understand the more complex types of functions, so I appreciate the help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
The below code will create a running total value that then gets passed to the function. Please note that I didn't test the code below (since I didn't have a form with the same textbox/control names). Hopefully it gives you the right direction, but if you run into issues, please write back. Also, I added comments to the code to explain more or less what I was doing. If you need more insight on those, also write back. I didn't change the `FormattedRemainingBudget` function, so you can keep it as it is.

```
Sub recalc()
    Dim adjValue As String
    Dim runningTotal As Double
    
    'Initialize running total to 0
    runningTotal = 0
    
    If opt1Req Then 'if user chooses 1 job
        If optReduceReq Then
            runningTotal = runningTotal + CDbl(txtAdjustmentAmt.Value)
        ElseIf optRemoveReq Then
            runningTotal = runningTotal + CDbl(txtBudgetImpact.Value)
        End If
    ElseIf opt2Reqs Then
        If optReduceReq_2 Then
            runningTotal = runningTotal + CDbl(txtAdjustmentAmt_2.Value)
        ElseIf optRemoveReq_2 Then
            runningTotal = runningTotal + CDbl(txtBudgetImpact_2.Value)
        End If
    End If

    'Since the FormattedRemainingBudge function expects
    'the adjustment as a string, we can either convert
    'running total to a string, or we can change the function
    'to expect a Double. I'd recommend changing the function
    'to accept a double since it will convert the string to a
    'Double anyway. However, if that function is used in other
    'places, and you change it, it might break code elsewhere.
    'Below I'm going to convert the double to a string, but the
    'option is yours based on the potential use cases.
    
    adjValue = Str(runningTotal)
    
    txtFunctionExcess.Value = FormattedRemainingBudget( _
        txtBudget.Value, adjValue) 'departments excess $
    
    End If
End Sub
```

There's no need to repeat the `Function FormattedRemainingBudget` function. They both do the same exact thing but with different variable names.

The two subroutines `Recalc` and `Recalc_v2` essentially do the same thing as well. You can rewrite it as something like:

```
Sub recalc()
    Dim adjValue as String

    If opt1Req Then 'if user chooses 1 job
        if optReduceReq then 
            adjValue = txtAdjustMentAmt.Value
        elseif optRemoveReq then
            adjValue = txtBudgetImpact.Value
        end if 

        txtFunctionExcess.Value = FormattedRemainingBudget( _                 
            txtBudget.Value, adjValue) 'departments excess $
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what about the function? do I keep it as is?

Comment: @NidenK Yes, the function is fine as it is.

Comment: So I used two scenarios (job 1 adj, job 1 removal), but I have a few others. Editing my post to incorporate that change.

Comment: I added in another scenario. What I posted was a basic example, but if `opt2Reqs` is clicked then I need to tack onto the calc to subtract whatever in the first job was clicked (removal or readjust) and then include which of those in the second job and then subtract that from `txtbudget`. does that make sense?

Comment: @NidenK How is your workbook laid out? Are there option buttons/checkboxes on the worksheet? Are you using a userform?

Comment: using a userform

Comment: I will upload a pic

Comment: @NidenK You can just build up a variable to aggregate the total values. For example: `Dim totalChanges as Double` then `If opt1value.... totalChanges = totalChanges + txtOpt1.value`... You'd do this for each scenario, and then use that as your total adjusted value. I will mention, however, that when I see a layout like this, it's generally a poor design. What happens when you need more than 2 requests? You will have 5 or 10 different conditions to work with. I think you should consider different application designs.

Comment: Luckily, there will never be more than 2 jobs to take away from, so that is staying as-is. I am a little confused on how to incorporate what you just added. is there any way you could incorporate that in your answer to give me a better idea?

Comment: @NidenK I made an edit to my post. Take a look and let me know if that gets you in the right direction.

Comment: I edited my post to account for all scenarios based on your edit. Can you let me know if this is what I'm looking for?